# "source script" does not honor "#!/bin/bash -ex" and exit when a command fails

Tags: bash, shell

I get confused after google search "set -e" in bash. Based on my understanding, with "set -e" the bash will exit whenever there is an error. But if you run two simple scripts below in mac such as `source myscript`, you can still see "can not get here"...Any idea?

```
#!/bin/bash -ex 
fun_with_error_code() {
  return 1;
}
fun_with_error_code
echo "can not get here"
```

Another one

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
commandNotExit
echo "can not get here"
```

My rookie mistake. Charles Duffy's answer below solves the problem. These two scripts work fine, it is just because "source myscript" doesn't honor shebang line.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). `set -e` is not reliable, predictable, or otherwise a thing that reasonable people should use... and if you *do* want to use it, you should put `set -e` as its own line instead of relying on the shebang.

Comment: (...to expand -- why not rely on the shebang? If you run `bash yourscript`, that ignores the shebang line completely).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hello Charles, I run the command "source myscript"

Comment: `source` doesn't read your shebang.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I saw the post it is not reliable. But for this simple script, should "-e" work by simply exit the bash rather than print "can not get here"?

Comment: ...so, you might re-title this something like *"source script" does not honor "#!/bin/bash -ex" and exit when a command fails*

Comment: It should, *if you were actually enabling it*. `#!/bin/bash -ex` does not enable `set -e` in a script invoked with `source`.

Comment: Oh. Any suggestion how to run the script so it will honor the shebang line?

Comment: I told you in the very first comment. Put `set -e` on its own line instead of in the shebang. That said, note that if you're `source`ing the script, that will enable `-e` in your interactive shell, which you may not want.

Comment: ...generally speaking, you should run scripts in their own interpreter. Thus, `./myscript` (which will honor the shebang), not `source myscript` (which doesn't start its own separate interpreter, and thus *can't* honor the shebang).

Comment: Oh. Forgive my rookie mistake. ./myscript works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shebang line is used to let a script tell the operating system what interpreter to run it with.

When you use `source`, you're telling your *current shell interpreter* to evaluate the script's commands internally.

Thus, the operating system doesn't need to start a new interpreter for the script.

Thus, the operating system never invokes the shebang line.

Thus, arguments such as `-ex` on that line are never invoked when your script is run with `source`.

---

Solutions are twofold:

- Use `set -e` as a separate line if you really do want to have this effect (but see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for reasons why you shouldn't).
- Don't use `source` except when you have a *very explicit reason* to run a script within your existing interpreter (and change that interpreter's state). And when you *do* have such a reason, running `set -e` is almost certainly a thing you don't want to do.